# PHP Multiple Input type Text and input type File form output to array name and Value with array Sequence

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, forms

I want to make a *Dynamic HTML Form* using array but whenever I fill the form the output doesn't get the array sequence with value. I found this problem when I use `input type="file"` but if I use only the text fields `input type="text"` it works properly properly..

**Here is the My Code `textfile.php`**

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    if(isset($_POST['data_value'])) {
        foreach ($_POST['data_value'] as $data_name => $data_value) {
          echo $_POST['data_name'][$data_name].' - '.$data_value."<br>";
        }
    }
    $textQnty = empty($_POST['data_value'])? 0: count($_POST['data_value']);
    if(isset($_FILES['data_value'])) {
        foreach ($_FILES['data_value']['name'] as $data_name => $data_value) {
            $file_name = $_FILES['data_value']['name'][$data_name];
            echo $_POST['data_name'][$data_name + $textQnty].' - '.$file_name."<br>";
        }
    }
}
?> 
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
<head> 
<title>Test File</title> 
</head> 
<body> 
    <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data"> 
        <?php 
        $data_array = array('text', 'file2', 'file', 'text2'); 
        foreach($data_array as $data_name) { ?> 
            <input type="hidden" name="data_name[]" value="<?php echo $data_name; ?>"> 
            <?php
            if(strpos($data_name,'text') !== false){ ?> <input name="data_value[]" type="text" /> <?php }
            if(strpos($data_name,'file') !== false){ ?> <input name="data_value[]" type="file" /> <?php } 
        } ?>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Add" /> 
    </form> 
</body> 
</html>
```

**Here is How I Output (Need Array Sequence)**

```
Array Sequence - array('text', 'file2', 'file', 'text2');
But Result - 
text - First of Text input Data
file2 - Second of Text input Data
file - First of file input Data
text2 - Second of file input Data
```

**I Need an Output Like This (According to Array Sequence)**

```
text - First of Text input Data
file2 - First of file input Data
file - Second of file input Data
text2 - Second of Text input Data
```

My code working fine I just need some basic improvements. Thanks!

Comment: is it important for you to use `name=data_value[]` ?

Comment: name=data_value[] Yes this is Importent for me

Answer (score 0):

Based on the `$data_array`, you can sequentially display the submitted values.

```
$data_array = array('text', 'file2', 'file', 'text2');

if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $text = 0;
    $file = 0;
    foreach ($data_array as $data) {
        if(strpos($data, 'text') !== false) {
            echo $_POST['data_value'][$text]."<br>";
            $text++;
        } else {
            echo $_FILES['data_value']['name'][$file]."<br>";
            $file++;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks For Your answer but I need `data_name`  also this is most important for me..